# Drilled thru end of web floor truss

Tags: repair, truss

Attempting to run conduit from exterior of house for a hottub. After drilling I noticed I went thru the vertical end of a open end floor truss and far end triangulation.  1 inch hole. This was not the plan, but an accident. I called the manufacturer about a repair. Glue and 3 inch screw two 24” pieces of 3/4 plywood on both sides of the truss. Also glue and screw 2 squash block 2x4 on each side to the plywood at the end.

Sound accurate?  The more information/confirmation I can get the better.

Comment: The manufacturer should have given the best advice, they should have engineers that know their stuff better than some idiot on the internet.  Best second opinion would be to get a structural engineer to look at it.

Comment: Do what the manufacturer says- otherwise hire an independent engineer to design a solution (to me this seems like a big waste of $)-